# WebLogic: Unrecognized Callback

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, weblogic12c, authenticator

After migrating my JAVA EE app. (Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework) from Ant to Maven I am getting this message while starting my app by WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0

```
Error 403--Forbidden         

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.4 403 Forbidden

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable
```

I've extracted an ear that is working with the new ear that is not working and I don't see any differences. Only a folder (jsp_servlet) that is not present in the new ear

..\myApp\myAppWeb\WEB-INF\classes\jsp_servlet

I went to the console http://localhost:7001/console and login. 
I invokeed the test page for the application using the console with the same result

```
/wls-cat/index.jsp (Classloader Analysis Tool on server myserver)
```

I see this error in the server logs

```
 javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException: Unrecognized Callback
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXAuthenticator$JMXCallbackHandler.handle(JMXAuthenticator.java:135)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.CallbackHandlerWrapper.handle(CallbackHandlerWrapper.java:76)
    at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl$CallbackHandlerWrapper.handle(WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl.java:154)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler$1.run(LoginContext.java:947)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler$1.run(LoginContext.java:944)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler.handle(LoginContext.java:943)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything except ant conf file to mvn pom, make sure you clean the project and build that one more time from mvn command. I will suggest to use gradle for migration, because mvn and ant are slightly different. In gradle you can combine the both functionalities.